# Segue to a different Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, segue

I'm trying to make a custom segue from one storyboard to another, I use a button and this method

```
-(void)VCtoUrbaVC{
UIStoryboard *urbaStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"BusUrbaStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *urbaVC = [urbaStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:urbaVC animated:YES];
}
```

but when I click the button in the simulator crashes saying "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'".

Debugging with breakpoints I found it does the execution of the metod OK but then it crashes.

Comment: Your initial view controller on BusUrbaStoryboard storyboard is a UINavigationController, if you want to push the view controller you should remove the UINavigationController and set the rootViewController as initial

Comment: great, answering to avoid let the question unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial view controller on BusUrbaStoryboard storyboard is a UINavigationController, if you want to push the view controller you should remove the UINavigationController and set the rootViewController as initial